# How can we verify if WAL-based shipping standby is working and synchronized in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I've setup a Wal Shipping (standby) in postgresql as:

In the master, I've enabled `archive_mode = on`, `archive_command` to a shared location between master & slave and `archive_timeout`.

In the slave, I've configured the `Restore_command` to recover those wal files from shared location and created a `standby.signal` file.

But how to monitor through SQL if the slave is synced and applying those logs?

I know in streaming replication we can:

```
-- on master
select * from pg_stat_replication;

-- On replica
select * from pg_stat_wal_receiver;
```

But what about a manual replication using wal Shipping?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Ok, edited with only one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this query on the standby to figure out the timestamp of the last transaction replayed from the primary:

```
SELECT pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp();
```

To see if the server is still a standby server, you can check if it is in recovery mode:

```
SELECT pg_is_in_recovery();
```